# understanding heap corruption in accessing memory

Tags: c++, memory, heap-memory

I am running a small sample. My code is

```
int main()
{
    char * mymem = new char[8];
    //1
    memcpy(mymem+8,"hello",5); //this cause heap corruption

    //2
    mymem[32]='a'; //this doesn't cause heap corruption

    //3
    delete [] mymem;

    return 0;
}
```

In the above code if i execute 1 then i get heap corruption on **delete** i.e 3 , 
 but if execute 2 then i dont get any heap corruption on delete i.e 3. I am curious to know why is this happening as in both cases i am trying to write outside the allocated memory.

Comment: They both cause heap corruption.  It's just that, by chance, you only observe a crash on the first example.

Comment: Both `//1` and `//2` are out of bounds access, which results in undefined behavior. It might corrupt the heap, or it might do something else, or nothing at all. It's undefined.

Comment: i tried to runit on both windows and linux but in the second case i didn't get heap corruption error

Comment: Nothing to add, you just shouldn't do that

Comment: but in the 2 case is it trying to write to stack memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior is undefined, but I will try to answer the question with an explanation of why in this case you get a heap corruption for the first access, but no heap corruption for the second access.

When you call `new[]` or `new`, some runtime libraries will allocate more memory than requested for the purpose of using the extra memory as `guard bytes`.  The amount of extra memory is usually only a few bytes more.

The purpose of the guard bytes is to detect if there is a change in value of these bytes when `delete[]` is issued.  If the guard bytes have changed when the deallocation occurs, then the system can detect that you have done something wrong.

More than likely, the runtime detected that you overwrote the guard bytes, thus can flag you for "heap corruption".  However, when you wrote to `mymem[32]`, that is outside the guard bytes that were allocated (I highly doubt the system allocated 32 bytes as guard bytes), thus the runtime couldn't detect you wrote outside the allocated space.

Comment: thanks..i tried changing memcpy to use an offset 0f 8 and it was doing the same thing as 2

Comment: There may be more than 8 bytes used as guard bytes.  It depends on the runtime library.

Answer (score 1):

You are writing outside the allocated memory in both cases and this invokes *undefined behavior*. Once there is UB, you may get either expected or unexpected result.